# StorageBackend version is incompatible with current JanusGraph version

Tags: janusgraph

Unable to start gremlin-server due to version mismatch. How can I fix this issue?

Here is the full stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:89)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:110)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:110)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: StorageBackend version is incompatible with current JanusGraph version: storage [0.2.1] vs. runtime [0.2.0]
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1427)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.lambda$open$0(JanusGraphFactory.java:152)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.openGraph(JanusGraphManager.java:210)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:151)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:101)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.lambda$new$0(JanusGraphManager.java:65)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.<init>(JanusGraphManager.java:64)
    ... 8 more
Exception in thread "gremlin-server-shutdown" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.stop(GremlinServer.java:264)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.lambda$new$0(GremlinServer.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am working with janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2.zip downloaded from janusgraph website. I don't know why the error says it has janusgraph 0.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Downloading janusgraph-0.2.1-hadoop2.zip and starting cassandra and gremlin-server running

```
./janusgraph-0.2.1-hadoop2/bin/cassandra
./janusgraph-0.2.1-hadoop2/bin/gremlin-server.sh
```

resolved the issue

**Note**  : I also modified the /janusgraph-0.2.1-hadoop2/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml and gremlin-server-configuration.yaml files to use conf/janusgraph-cassandra.properties for ConfigurationManagementGraph property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following property in your configuration file. This property will allow upgrade and DB get compatible with the newer version.

**graph.allow-upgrade=true**

| Name | Description | Datatype | Default Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| graph.allow-upgrade | Setting this to true will allow certain fixed values to be updated such as storage-version. This should only be used for upgrading. | Boolean | false |